# Stacking together two I²C hats with different voltage

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, i2c

I plan to make a domotic system based on a raspberry pi.
I choose a [grove hat](https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-Base-Hat-for-Raspberry-Pi.html) to connect sensors and relays, but I need a digital potentiometer and grove system does not have that.

So I plan to buy one from ControlEverything, connected through [this shield.](https://shop.controleverything.com/collections/adapters/products/i2c-breakout-for-raspberry-pi-2-and-3-with-outward-facing-i2c-port)

Grove and CE hats are both I²C, but the first one operate at 3.3V, the other at 5V.

**Question**: can I stack those two hats together on the same raspberry pi? Maybe it's an obvious question, but I am very new on this domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CE shield and the Grove HAT should be fine together.

The CE shield is very light on detail.

My best guess is it is accessed via the standard Raspberry Pi I2C bus.

Connect any 5V I2C devices via the CE shield.  Connect any 3V3 I2C devices via the Grove HAT.